# Find orthogonal complement and its basis

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices

Let $U=\mbox{span}\left\{
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}\right\}$. What is a basis of orthogonal complement $U^{\perp}$?

So far I have deduced from the theorem
$$\mbox{dim}(U)+\mbox{dim}(U^{\perp})=\mbox{dim}(M_{2\times2})$$
that $\mbox{dim}(U^{\perp})=1$. Morover, if I pick a matrix $A\in M_{2\times 2}$ and conider
$$\langle A, M\rangle=0\qquad \mbox{for all}\, M\in U$$
I may assume that $M$ is linear combination of elements from $U$ (span) for some constants. I cannot however deduce the general form of the orthogonal complement from the latter.

Comment: What is the inner product on the space of matrices?

Comment: $\langle A, B \rangle=\mbox{tr}(A^T B)$

Comment: Note that $A\in U^{\perp}\iff A$ is orthogonal to each element of your basis of $U$.

Comment: So I may consider $\langle A, M_i \rangle =0$, where $M_i$ is the i-th element of span of $U$. This will give me some info about $A$, but how do you know it will give the whole orthogonal complement?

Comment: Because I wrote an **equivalence**! Could you prove it?

Comment: The first implication $\implies$ is obvious. As concerns the second one, I think it suffices to show $\langle M_i, M_j \rangle =0$ ?

Comment: No. Use the fact that you have a **basis** of U.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X \in U^{\perp} \iff \langle X, Y \rangle=0 \> \> \forall \> Y \in U $

$\langle X, Y \rangle=\mbox{tr}(X^T Y)$

Let's take: 
$X=\begin{pmatrix} 
a & b \\ 
c & d 
\end{pmatrix} $

\begin{equation}\text{tr} \Biggl(
\begin{pmatrix} a & c \\ b & d \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\Biggl)
= a + b = 0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\text{tr} \Biggl(
\begin{pmatrix} a & c \\ b & d \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\Biggl)
= a + c = 0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\text{tr} \Biggl(
\begin{pmatrix} a & c \\ b & d \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\Biggl)
= a + c + d = 0
\end{equation}
If you solve you'll get $d=0 \land b=-a \land c=b$.

So
$X=\begin{pmatrix} 
a & -a \\ 
-a & 0 
\end{pmatrix}, \> a \neq 0$.